# How to resolve laravel ui in Laravel Framework 7.29.3

Tags: laravel-7

I am currently using laravel 7.29.3 . i want install laravel ui auth using below command

```
composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

But its not working getting bellow respectively

```
 Problem 1
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.29.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.29.3
- laravel/ui 3.x-dev requires illuminate/filesystem ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
- laravel/ui v3.1.0 requires illuminate/filesystem ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/filesystem[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.10.0, v8.11.0, v8.11.1, v8.11.2, v8.12.0, v8.12.1, v8.12.2, v8.12.3, v8.13.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
- don't install
```

ANyone guide how to install laravel UI auth into my current version . Anyone have idea then let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be you should upgrade your laravel application's version to v8.x

**OR**

you should determine version of laravel/ui package to be satiable with your laravel application's version using this command `composer require laravel/ui "^2.1" --dev`

Answer (score 3):

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

Comment: WHat commands to run after that?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the older version of **Laravel UI** in Laravel 7.x.

```
composer require laravel/ui:^versionHere
```

for example,

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

For more information, you can follow the Laravel Docs. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#introduction

Comment: WHat commands to run after that? for instance, while i was searching for answers, I found this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/in-order-to-use-the-authroutes-method-please-install-the-laravelui-package?reply=777056